# What's the best approach to analyse a SharePoint 2013 solution?

Tags: solution-package

We have a SharePoint 2013 solution which we are going to merge with another common solution which is platform wide.
The tasks are to identify the components which can be removed entirely, can be added in the common solution, basically killing the current solution.
We do not have license of SPCAF.
What could be the approach?
1. Manual study of solution components? But it's a huge solution with hundreds of site collections impacted.
2. Any power shell to get the custom features? But what about other components?

Comment: Both approaches you mentioned seem to be hard to go through because of the bulk of input and outputs we consider. I rather tend to compare the activated custom features. But what about "other components"? Could you give an example why you are in doubt here?

Comment: Other components like Timer jobs, site providers, user controls, etc